# Yii2 bindValue in LIKE condition

Tags: php, yii2, bindvalue

How can I do a wildcard search using bindValue(:name, $name) in LIKE condition given this query:

```
$post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE %:name%')
       ->bindValue(':name', 'apple')
       ->queryOne();
```

Comment: The result of that query is this " WHERE name LIKE %'apple'% " which of course gives an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this and it does as I need.

```
$post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE :name')
   ->bindValue(':name', '%apple%')
   ->queryOne();
```